# Perl CGI::Session - Migrating user sessions to new server, without them knowing it

Tags: perl, session, cgi

I need to move our perl apps to a new server, but I don't want everyone to have to re-authenticate when the move is made. I'd like to have our "Home" script redirect over to the new server, pre-plant a cookie, with a corresponding session file in /tmp, for each user before I make the DNS change.

Thought it would be simple but it's turning out not to be. That or I'm just missing something right in front of my face.

Here is the code I put in the "Home" script on the current server..

```
my $has_session = $cgi->param("session") || "";
if ($has_session eq "") {
    my $url = "http://111.222.333.444/cgi-bin/SetNewSession.cgi?back=http://" . "$ENV{SERVER_NAME}" ."$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}";
    print "Location: $url\n\n";
}
```

And here is the code in a script on the new server...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $userid = $cgi->param("userid");
my $redir_back = $cgi->param("back");
my $session = CGI::Session->load() or die $!;
my $session_userid = $session->param("userid");

if (! defined $session_userid) {

    $session->expire("9y");
    $session->param("userid",$userid);
    $session->flush();
}

my $url = $redir_back . "?session=1";
print $session->header(-location=>$url);
exit;
```

No cookie. No session file. Nothing.

P.S. Please, no flak for the 9y expiration. Management is "above" having to login. :)

Comment: Which session storage driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the code I put in the "Home" script on the current server..

That part doesn't seem to transmit userid, it also doesn't use [url](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Obtaining-the-scripts-url)`(qw/ -full 1 -rewrite 1 /)` to retrieve the url value for back=

You also might want to [Crypt::CBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::CBC) userid (and even back) using rjindel like [Session::Storage::Secure](https://metacpan.org/pod/Session::Storage::Secure) does for cookies (UTSL)

> And here is the code in a script on the new server... No cookie. No session file. Nothing.

The way I read your program, it should have at least throw an error because [load](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#load) won't create a session, its called load() its not called new. [new](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#new) will create a session.

Comment: Yep! userid was not being passed from the "Home" script. The "if..." needed a new session created. Thanks @optional.